# resize textarea to fit in a fluid width layout with javascript

Tags: javascript, layout, textarea, resizable, fluid

I have a fluid layout and i need a textarea to expand/reduce depending of the size of the parent container.

In CSS it would look like this:

```
textarea{
width: 100%;
}
```

But this doesn´t work with textareas.

How can I do this with javascript? I can get the parent element width and them calculate the number of cols to fit that width but how do I know the size of 1 col (in px)?

Answer (score 13):

chk this out : http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

```
  textarea {
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
             box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
           }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's 2014, and `width: 100%;` now works with **textareas** in current versions of Chrome, Firefox, IE, Opera, and Safari.